# How can I administer Netware via a vitual machine (VirtualBox perhaps)?

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox, novell

We have several Novell Netware file sharing that we are inheriting. This is temporary and we are transitioning to our Samba based file sharing.

For the time being, I need to be able to login to Novell for administration tasks. However, when I installed the Novell client on a VirtualBox instance, I was not able to find the Trees.

I do not know much about Novell. How do I get this working on a VirtualBox instance? It's running on a Windows XP guest with an Windows 7x64 host.

Comment: As long as the Virtualbox guest can interact with the network, it should be good to go. Can you ping other servers in the network, query DNS, etc?

Comment: You administer Netware from a virtual machine exactly the same way you would from a physical machine. As far as your Netware server is concerned it's the same as any other computer on the network...

Comment: voretaq7: When I click "trees" button under eDirectory, I do not see any trees.

Comment: What version of Netware? For version 5 and above you can use pure IP (no IPX), and SLP may or may not be required depending on your DNS setup.

Answer (score 3):

As SpacemanSpiff noted, SLP is used to find servers and trees.

However, if you cannot get multicast out the network connection, I would consider just entering the IP address/IP Name of the server or tree to try and connect.  That will work even if SLP is not working, most of the time.

Answer (score 2):

Novell trees and resources are typically located via SLP, one or more of the netware servers is an SLP DA, and you should configure the novell client to point at the server that is the DA.

From there, as for administration, you should either configure RCONJ or use Novell remote manager to manage the box. This should be sufficient with minimum configuration necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I've always used Netware with IPX/SPX for main protocol and only used IP for some of the specific apps that required it.  You may need to install your client with IPX and then try searching for the tree.

Answer (score 1):

Nimmy,

You can also use this free utility to connect to the NetWare server remotely: http://rconip.sourceforge.net/